# Redirecting and Remapping with mod_rewrite

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite, url-routing

First of all, am new to doing back-end server admin.. 
I have a main website being served on at certain IP. I have a blog address that lives on another IP, which was used on wordpress.com. When a user typed in blog.domain.com it would resolve to the Wordpress.com site. Since coming on board (two months) they wanted me to bring the blog in house. So, I set up a wordpress install at domain.com/blog.

I would like blog.domain.com (different ip) to resolve to domain.com/blog but still using blog.domain.com  is this possible with Apache and mod_rewrite?

Answer (score 1):

Easiest option would be to alter the DNS record for:

**blog.domain.com**, such that it points to the same IP address as: **domain.com**, you could simply make it a CNAME for the latter.

Then Either:

1) Enable name based VirtualHosts in Apache and set-up a new Apache **Virtualhost** section for blog.domain.com, there's a section detailing this on the Apache site, and set it's document root to be the Wordpress /blog/ root.

2) If name based virtual hosting is already enabled alternatively add **blog.domain.com** as a ServerAlias within the existing **domain.com** virtualhost, along with the following rule:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName  domain.com
    ServerAlias blog.domain.com

    RewriteEnging On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} blog.domain.com   [NC]
    RewriteRule ^$  /blog/  [L]          
...
```